# Can I override kotlin method which returns Unit type in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, overriding

Main Question: **How can I override kotlin method in java which returns Unit type?**

I'm trying to use kotlin library in java and there is a method which name is `override fun invoke(): Unit` that I have to implement.

but, java compiler keep telling me `return type void is not compatible with Unit`.

I tried `public Unit invoke() { return Unit.INSTANCE; }` in java but occurs compile error.

```
invoke()' in 'myproject' clashes with 'invoke()' in 'library'; 
attempting to use incompatible return type
```

---

kotlin interface (in library)

```
interface MessageHandler<M : Message> : (Message) -> Unit {

  override fun invoke(message: Message): Unit =
    if (messageType.isAssignableFrom(message.javaClass)) {
      println("invoked ${message.javaClass.simpleName}")
    } else {
      throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported message type ${message.javaClass.simpleName}")
    }

}
```

java abstract class (in my project)

```java
public abstract class AbstractMessageHandler<T extends Message> implements MessageHandler<T> {

    @Override
    public void invoke(@NotNull Message message) {
        //this is where the compile error occurs.
    }
}
```

error message

```
(Message) in AbstractMessageHandler cannot implement invoke(P1) in Function1
    public void invoke(@NotNull Message message) {
                ^
  return type void is not compatible with Unit
  where P1,R are type-variables:
    P1 extends Object declared in interface Function1
    R extends Object declared in interface Function1
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? I used `void` as the return type and there is no error.

Comment: @Sweeper, I added the example. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a 4-year old unresolved bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15964

Quoted:

> I don't think this is possible now because of
> compatibility with older binaries. We'll see what we can do, thank you
> for the report.
>
> An ugly workaround would be to use the nullable type `Unit?`:
>
> ```
> interface TestA<out T> {
>     fun foo(): T
> }
>
> abstract class TestB : TestA<Unit?> {
>     override fun foo(): Unit? {
>         // ...
>         return Unit
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> With this, you won't be required to override `foo` in a Java subclass.
> If you want to override it though, the signature in the Java subclass
> should be `public Unit foo()`.

If you don't control the library, I'm not sure there's much you can do.

Comment: Oh...That's bad news for me. I can't control the library. I will find another way. Thank you for the answering!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you control the Kotlin library you can :

- Inherit from `java.util.function.Consumer`:

  ```
  interface MessageHandler<M : Message> : Consumer<Message> {

       override fun accept(message: Message): Unit =
           if (messageType.isAssignableFrom(message.javaClass)) {
               println("invoked ${message.javaClass.simpleName}")
           } else {
               throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported message type ${message.javaClass.simpleName}")
           }

  }
  ```
- Or use `Any` instead of `Unit` and return `null` in your Java code:

  ```
    interface MessageHandler<M : Message> : (Message) -> Any {

    override fun accept(message: Message): Any =
        if (messageType.isAssignableFrom(message.javaClass)) {
            println("invoked ${message.javaClass.simpleName}")
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported message type ${message.javaClass.simpleName}")
        }

  }
  ```

2. If you can't, I think it's better, and if possible, to write `AbstractMessageHandler` and all its sub classes in Kotlin:

   ```
   abstract class AbstractMessageHandler : MessageHandler<Message> {
      override fun invoke(message: Message) {
       // ...
      }
   }
   ```

- But and if you won't call the default `MessageHandler.invoke` and your code won't relate on `MessageHandler` type, you can simply inherit from`java.util.function.Consumer`:

  ```
    public  class AbstractMessageHandler implements Consumer<Message> {
       @Override
       public void accept(Message message) {
          // ...
       }
    }
  ```

---

Just to mention that before the error:

```
(Message) in AbstractMessageHandler cannot implement invoke(P1) in Function1
...
```

You should see something like:

```
'invoke(Message)' in '...MessageHandler' clashes with 'invoke(P1)' in 
'kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

Because the Java compiler see two interfaces, one from `(Message) -> Unit`:

```
public interface kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 {
   Object invoke(Messsage var1);
}
```

and the other from `MessageHandler`:

```
public interface MessageHandler extends Function1 {
   void invoke(@NotNull Message var1);
}

// (Some details were ommitted for simplicity)
```

And this is not possible in Java, as `MessageHandler.invoke` try to override `Function1.invoke` with different return type, as stated in [jls-8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3),

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the
> declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be
> return-type-substitutable ([§8.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)) for d2, or a compile-time error
> occurs.